# Can a Fake business card save me of trouble in Morocco?

Tags: morocco, scams, deception

I Will be traveling to Morocco in May, and I have being reading a lot about being harassed, scamed by locals and maybe even police.

I know of a friend who runs a very successful business and when visiting morocco he got into trouble with the police and got out of it handing them his business cards and telling them he had connections that could get them in trouble.

My question is: How legit is this? I'm very tempted to do some business cards with a fake e-mail and phone number and telling them I work for an important company or maybe even pretend I'm a diplomat some made up international association from the EU(I'm a EU citizen), because I'm very frightened by this sort of encouters and scams.

Can I get in trouble for this? If I happen to come up with some international organization and claim I work for them to scare them?

Comment: Never lie to police and other officials. And certainly do not claim to be a diplomat, that will give big trouble when found out.

Comment: *when visiting morocco he got into trouble with the police* What exactly was the trouble? I think the best thing to do would be not to get into any trouble with the police.

Comment: @MJeffryes he said the police tried to give him a ticket for something he didnt do. From my searches abouts scams in morocco this seems to be something that may happen. It seems to be  a common scam among corrupt officers

Comment: Note that your friend was making vague unverifiable threats on the basis of something that was verifiably true ("I work for this big company" or, at least, "This big company exists") whereas you're proposing to make vague unverifiable threats on the basis of something that can be shown to be false ("I work for this non-existent organization"). That doesn't sound good. Especially when "I'm a diplomat" is such an important claim that they'd be pretty much forced to check right there.

Comment: Relax.  I went on holiday to Morocco and had a great time.  You will get hassled by people wanting to sell you stuff, and by the poor begging for alms.  In both cases you can say "no" without difficulty.

Comment: I can't imagine threatening the police in any country is a good strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make pretty impressive business cards, with a company name on it and a function you 'do' within that company.

But make sure you have the right to make those cards, to hand them out and to claim to be what the card shows.
In many countries you can start a business without having to jump through hoops like getting it registered. And when you have one such a company you can call yourself the CEO of it, have a working e-mail to that company and a website.

But on checking it will show you are a newly started or a false front business and if you fall in the hands of a police officer who is a bit more savvy and checks your claims, you can get in deeper trouble than if you had not used that card.
It would be better to have a business card from your current job, with your actual function on it, with the business e-mail address and telephone number, so that if you do run into trouble and you are checked you will not get into more trouble because of the card you hand over.

Whatever you do, never claim to be a diplomat, as that is easy to be checked.
Real diplomats have special passports, they are known by the country they claim to be diplomats for and so on.
If you are claiming to have official status and it shows you do not have it, they can hold you till it has been proven who you really are, whether you have something to hide and they may suspect you of something worse, like being part of a network of people working against the country, being a spy or whatever.

Never lie to the police, and officers of justice and border control, as when found out it will make your problems much worse.

Comment: Thank you  , great answer. I might do some business cards with my actual job then, that altough is not very important has a fancy title maybe that will look important enough to scare off some corrupt officer.

Comment: In particular, if corrupt police try to pin a fake crime on you, it might be difficult for them to get official support, e.g., from the rest of the police and the courts. But if you commit the actual crime of lying to them by pretending to be a diplomat, they will have the full support of the legal system behind them.

Comment: Hmm. If the visa in your passport is a tourist visa not a business visa, handing business cards to a corrupt cop as a foreigner sounds like a fast way to increase the amount of trouble they could get you in, and therefore the size of the bribe they'll expect you to pay if they're smart.

Comment: I guess most business people on holiday have a few business cards in their belongings, which come in handy when having to give contact information to a police officer.

Comment: Why would pretending to be important make someone seeking money less likely to bother you?